# How to convert SIMD bash commands into GPU processable commands?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gpu, gnu-parallel

Consider a SIMD kind of code which extracts all instances of a pattern match from a file like this:

`grep grep -n <some_pattern>`

This can be made faster using GNU Parallel and some modifications like this

`cat fileName | parallel -j{cores} --pipe --block {chunk_size}M --cat LC_ALL=C grep -n '/some_pattern/'`

I can also use `xargs` to make the parallel execution if the single input file is split into multiple separate files:

`xargs -P {cores} -L {line_per_process} bash -c grep {1}< fileID*`

But this kind of parallelism is limited by the number of CPU cores that you can have.

I am interested in knowing whether there is any way to convert such commands into GPU(CUDA) threads?
The whole task can be broken into chunks equal to the number of CPU cores and then each CPU Core processes those chunks as individual threads in GPUs?

Comment: **Q1:** How did you arrive to an assumption, that GNU parallel operates in a SIMD-fashion ( by what mechanism it "glues"-among-all-CPU-cores the **same** **S**-ingle **I**-nstruction, so as to positively qualify for being named a SIMD-mode of execution )? **Q2:** Have you ever tried to move a few GB of data from host-side into the device-side memory ( GPU ) and what was your hands-on experience of latency and throughput of such attempt? **Q3:** What has started your considerations that SIMD-GPU-kernels get any edge from SIMD-processing with ~350~450 [ns] access-latency to GPU-RAM at << 2GHz?

Answer (score 2):

I will be surprised if there is such a way. `grep` is not like a matrix multiplication where you do exactly the same machine code instruction for every byte. On the contrary, `grep` does a lot of optimization for different situations (e.g. if current byte does not match, skip this many bytes ahead).

So while you may call this Same Command Multiple Data (SCMD), it does not qualify as SIMD at the machine code level.

That does not mean that there is no way to convert `grep` into real SIMD, but this is not going to be automatic. You will have to rewrite `grep` using algorithms that are suitable for GPUs. And that can clearly be done: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15418-s12/www/competition/bkase.github.com/CUDA-grep/finalreport.html

If you want to convert another tool than `grep` you will again have to rewrite that tool. Possibly using some of the algorithms that you used for `grep`, but not necessarily: It might be that you have to use completely different algorithms.

Comment: **Just for the record:** it is pitty those students were permitted to publish benchmarks without a complete cost - **they knowingly omitted both the setup-costs and termination costs from the *speedup marketing*** of their work - "This is without taking into account the overhead of transferring data to the GPU."

Answer (score 1):

Normally you will be limited by your disk (your disk is slow, `grep` is fast).

If you have really fast disks try:

```
parallel -a filename -k --pipepart --block -1 LC_ALL=C grep '/some_pattern/'
```

`--pipe` can deliver in the order of 100MB/s total. `--pipepart` can deliver in the order of 1 GB/s *per* *core* (and usually your disks cannot deliver 1 GB/s/core). `--block -1` chops `filename` into one block per job on the fly.

Unfortunately you lose the ability to see the line number (so `grep -n` will give the wrong answer).

If your `grep` is still limited by CPU, then you should probably ask another question and elaborate on why your `grep` is so CPU intense.

Comment: My question only gives an example of grep. I am not asking a specific case but a general question on how a SIMD bash code can be transformed into GPU compatible code. Like using xargs to initiate processes with the number of lines or chunks and then breaking each command inside chunk into individual independent runs to be processed using GPU. This I think can resolve the issue of hardisk limit of data transfer